# Plane passing through two points, parallel to a vector $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: geometry

\begin{align}
P &= (1,1,0,1) \\
Q &= (1,2,1,2) \\
M &= (3,2,-1,1) \\
N &= (4,2,-1,2)
\end{align}

The plane is parallel to $MN$ and passes through $PQ$.

Comment: I tried to calculate the cross product MNxPQ.  I am having trouble because it is not a 3d plane.

Comment: You know a point of the plane (say $P$) and two vectors $PQ$ and $MN.$ That is enough.

Comment: I am trying to create a matrix to find the equation of the line.
|x   y  z   t |
|-1 0  0  -1|
|0  -1 -1 -1|
|                |
I do not know what to put in the last row...

Comment: Do you mean a two-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$? Its equation is not going to be in the form $Ax+By+Cz+Dt=E$, because such an equation defines a three-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. You'll have to give the answer either in parametric form or as intersection of two hyperplanes.

Comment: x=1+(-1)*k+0*v;
y=1+(0)*k+(-1)*v;
z=0+(0)*k+(-1)*v;
t=1+(-1)*k+(-1)*v;
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any plane is of the form $v_0+\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Since $P, Q\in v_0+\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$, then $Q-P\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Also, $MN$ being parallel to the plane means $N-M\in \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$.

Now, $Q-P = (0,1,1,1)$ and $N-M = (1,0,0,1)$ are linearly independent, thus $\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\} = \operatorname{span}\{(0,1,1,1), (1,0,0,1)\}$.

Finally, since $P$ lies in the plane, we can choose $v_0$ to be $P$, which gives us that the plane is $$\{(1+s,1+t,t,1+t+s)\mid t,s\in\mathbb R\}.$$